# Swapping ctrl and cmd keys on a per-application basis

Tags: macos, mac

Mac OS lets you swap ctrl and cmd keys.
Is there a way to have them swapped on a per-application basis?

Basically I'm trying to run a terminal (via "Terminal" or X11 emulator or what not) and have the key mappings re-reversed.  (System-wide, I need ctrl and cmd swapped, but that messes up my terminal, so I'd like to unswap them just when running that application)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [IronAHK](http://code.google.com/p/ironahk/) with [`#IfWinActive`](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_IfWinActive.htm).

Comment: How close to the windows AHK is that?

Comment: Full rewrite apparently, with features added for Linux/Mac.

Comment: Brilliant! One less barrier to using linux full time :)

Comment: can you elaborate?  how would i set this up?

Comment: You'll need to download it via svn (see http://code.google.com/p/ironahk/source/checkout ). It comes with a makefile. Run under Mono (may need to install Mono if you haven't already - http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page )